# PHP magic methods with array properties

Tags: php

When reviewing some code, I found the following construct, specifically the array ($this[$key]).  How does it work?  Where does it put the values? Where can I find it documented?

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this[$key];
}
```

Answer: Thanks Mario.  It's implemented by adding the ArrayAccess interface to the object and implementing offsetGet and offsetSet methods.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: Aha - arrayaccess.  Thanks mario.

Comment: Hard to tell without context. This one is more likely derived from `ArrayObject`. With `ArrayAccess` you'd use `offsetGet` instead of `__get` usually.

Comment: I'm working through Laravel.  The Container class uses this method, implementing both the magic methods, and the ArrayAccess interface to allow either calling method to work.

Answer (score 2):

That's a getter, there's not much to it than what you see. You access a private object's properties.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: It's the array access bit that I'm not understanding.
$this[$key]

Comment: $this is a private variable you have in the class. For example you have a private variable $name; With this function you get the value of $this['name'] if you call the function __get('name')